# Downsides of changing the method to virtual to mock the method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, virtual

I have code something similar to this.

```
[TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<EmailService>();
        mock.Setup(x => x.SendEmail()).Returns(true);
        var cus = new Customer();
        var result = cus.AddCustomer(mock.Object);
        Assert.IsTrue(result);
    }

public class Customer
{
    public bool AddCustomer(EmailService emailService)
    {
        emailService.SendEmail();
        Debug.WriteLine("new customer added");
        return true;
    }
}

public class EmailService
{            
    public bool SendEmail()
    {
        throw  new Exception("send email failed cuz bla bla bla");
    }
}
```

The EmailService.SendEmail method must be virtual to mock it as there are no interfaces in this code.

In order to make the test case run, if I change the method to virtual,I want to know if there is any problem or downsides for doing so, when the actual application runs?

Comment: that is not an option, because the code is already written and now it is a very heavy code which I'm working on. So wanted to know if I can change the methods to virtual and proceed with that.

Comment: but then you probably can't make `SendMail` virtual either, can you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem with that. Only that you will open the door for other coders to modify the behaviour of your class (usuallly you are your worst enemy and you have to be kind of protected from yourself ;)

You are breaking the recommendation of =>closed for modification open for extension (SOLID).
 Also keep in mind that if you have to do such things is because you are depending on concrete implementations instead of abstractions

```
public interface IEmailService
{            
    bool SendEmail();
}

 public class EmailService:IEmailService
{            
    public bool SendEmail()
    {
       throw  new Exception("send email failed cuz bla bla bla");
    }
}

public class Customer
{
   public bool AddCustomer(IEmailService emailService)
   {
       emailService.SendEmail();
       Debug.WriteLine("new customer added");
       return true;
   }
}


//unit test => no need to make virtual anything
var mock = new Mock<IEmailService>();
mock.Setup(x => x.SendEmail()).Returns(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As of now, there is no one working on this code along with me.So assuming that no one will override this method in future, I hope there is no other problem!

Comment: Ok, you will need to cross your fingers then. please Check as asnwer if you are ok with that. Thanks dude